# How can pawns win a whole game without any strong pieces?

Tags: online-chess, pawns, pawn-structure

**How can a pawn or two or three win a entire chess game on it's own?**

I am playing as white pawns on the chessboard against my opponent. I tried moving to the end of the other and trading it for a strong piece. The opponent took my queen out with his bishop. This is a challenge I am willing to take on without moving any other pieces, and it can be easy eliminated.

*What are a few tips I can use to defend my pawns from getting eliminated by strong pieces?*

**Attempts**

- I tried using some of my pawns to defend one pawn, but the knights and the rooks take advantage over them. (#Attempt 1)
- I put 2 pawns in front of the regular pawn by match, but the rook slid under, camping the low one. Because it is on the 4 row and all my other pawns can capture it. (#Attempt 2)
- I tried using 5-7 pawns, but I couldn't because the opponent needs it's turn. (#Attempt 3)

  ---

  **What I expect in the answer**
  I need tips on what I can do with some pawns that can get me a victory, and I need advantage:
- Advantage Tips
- Number of recommended pawns
- Rare Strategies
  *If possible, list a few defense tips*.

  ---

  P.S.: **I play on the internet.**

Comment: This sounds like a training mode somewhere on the 'Net, and a link would help (since from your description I guess this is played by chess piece rules, but not chess rules). Even if, endgame books describe strategies. E.g.: a knight or bishop can easily stop 3 connected pawns. Or: A rook make mincemeat out of pawns, but when they are on the 6th rank, they are unstoppable. Or: Diagonal chains are hard to attack, but easy to block. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try use pawn chain to defend your pawns? Say if a pawn is at a2(white) and you want to defend  a pawn at b4 just move the pawn at a2 to a3. If a roke or a queen tries to take b4 it is defended by a3. If a roke tries take a3, it is defended by the roke at a1. It doesn't matter if you lost your queen or not. You can still win by make pawn chains and use your other peaces wisely with the pawns.